# Using built-in views to login

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I'm using built-in view to perform a user login:

```
(r'^login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login', {'template_name':'login.html'}),
```

where login.html is template. The login.html is loaded properly. However I need to pass my variable to template. I my own views I'm doing in the following way (**STATIC_URL**):

```
class AboutView(TemplateView):
template_name = 'about.html'

def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
    context = super(AboutView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
    context['STATIC_URL'] = settings.STATIC_URL
    return context
```

So, how can I pass "STATIC_URL" to "login.html" using built-in "django.contrib.auth.views.login" view?

Comment: STATIC_URL is needed to define path for additional css and js for template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

STATIC_URL should be passed automatically through the django's own context processors . In your settings file you need to define STATIC_URL . Also make sure the appropriate context processor is loaded.

'django.core.context_processors.static'

Answer (score 1):

refer this url https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/

You can follow the same process to get what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to pass `STATIC_URL` explicitly. You can make use of django's context processor  `'django.core.context_processors.static'` which is by default enabled.

Make sure you are using `RequestConext()` while rendering response from template.

You can get other ways to refer `STATUS_URL` in template [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/#referring-to-static-files-in-templates)